# How to add custom policy to a Service Linked Role in AWS using cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I am attempting to create an autoscaling group for my EC2 instances. These instances are encrypted by custom key, so I need to be able to inject a policy that allows the read of said key to the autoscaling group.

I decided to utilize the `ServiceLinkedRoleARN:` property of the AutoScalingGroup and create new autoscale role that would have all the necessary permissions.

Unfortunatelly, the properties of IAM::ServiceLinkedRole (SLR) do not offer policy inputs (unlike standard roles):

```
Type: AWS::IAM::ServiceLinkedRole
Properties: 
  AWSServiceName: String
  CustomSuffix: String
  Description: String
```

and so far I was unable to find a solution for this. If there is no way to modify the policies of SLR, I  even fail to see a reason for allowing to create our own SLR so I imagine there has to be a reason for that.

Can you please help with how to resolve my problem? My company mandates that I use CloudFormation for that so no console adjustments are possible, but using the custom SLR is not necessary, it just felt like the cleanest solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't modify** service-linked role for Auto Scaling:

> With the AWSServiceRoleForAutoScalingPlans_EC2AutoScaling role created by AWS Auto Scaling, you can edit only its description and **not its permissions**.

However, the KMS permissions should be added to your **instance role**, not service-linked role for Auto Scaling. So you have to change the role associated with your [AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html).